# Laravel 9 + Nova v4 + AWS S3 integration issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have followed this guide (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#amazon-s3-compatible-filesystems) and did the following.

I have tried several ways to integrate AWS s3, but it's not working:

1. I have created an open to public S3 instance
2. Added the CORS settings to it so that it could be accessed from my localhost machine: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            ""
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

3. Updated Block public access and deselected all
   Added bucket policy to:

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ""
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::NAME_OF_MY_BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

4. Updated filesystem config:

```php
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
    'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
    'throw' => false,
    'visibility' => 'public'
],
```

5. Required `"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.3"` via `composer`
6. But when I add the field into one of my modal

```php
Image::make('Media', 'image')
    ->disk('s3'),
```

It never uploads anything on my AWS bucket neither it displays any images

Comment: please show your code for uploading. Is the Image for Intervention package?

Comment: @parastoo I use Nova 4 "Image::make('Media', 'image')->disk('s3')," is the code which handles everything including upload and display

Comment: @Lonare you must have an error somewhere, check your chrom console and see if you have any errors there, also check your `storage/logs` and see if you have any recent Laravel errors